# Sentencia no muestra todos los datos

Tags: mysql

Tengo una sentencia que al ejecutarla en Workbench me genera una tabla con los datos de las solicitudes de vacaciones, dias extra, dias de baja, etc, de los empleados de una empresa. Mi problema es que solo me muestra los empleados que han realizado una solicitud (cualquier solicitud de vacaciones, dias de baja, etc...). Por ejemplo:

Tengo dos usuarios con 24 dias disponibles, usuario1 y usuario2. Si hacemos una solicitud de vacaciones por ejemplo con usuario1, al ejecutar la sentencia solo me muestra los datos de usuario1. Mi idea es que me muestre usuario1 y usuario2, aunque usuario2 no haya realizado ninguna solicitud.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
SELECT u.pk_user, u.name, u.apellidos, u.dias_disponibles,
       (u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) - COALESCE(ausencias,0)) AS dias_libres,
       COALESCE(dias_disfrutados,0) as dias_disfrutados,
       COALESCE(dias_baja,0) as dias_baja,
       COALESCE(dias_extra,0) as dias_extra,
       COALESCE(ausencias,0) as dias_ausencias,
       COALESCE(permisos,0) as dias_permisos,
       COALESCE(rechazadas,0) as solicitud_rechazadas
FROM (

     select u.pk_user, u.name, u.apellidos, u.dias_disponibles
          , sum( case when s.fk_estado_sup = 1 
                and (s.fk_motivo = 1) 
                then  N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end ) as dias_disfrutados
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 4 and FK_ESTADO_SUP = 1
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as dias_baja
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 2
            and (s.fk_estado_sup = 1 or s.fk_estado_sup = 2)
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as dias_extra
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 3
        and (s.fk_estado_sup = 1)
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as ausencias
          , sum( case when  FK_MOTIVO = 5
                then N_DIASSOLICITADOS else 0 end )  as permisos 
          , sum( case when  FK_ESTADO_SUP = 2
                then 1 else 0 end) as rechazadas

      FROM sec_users u 
      left join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.login
      where ano_diassolicitados = 2019
      group by u.pk_user) u
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: esto ano_diassolicitados  en que tabla esta? porque ese filtro, puede que te saque al usuario que vos queres...

Comment: Y el left join con la tabla solicitud. ¿Porque lo haces?

Comment: @gbianchi el campo `ano_diassolicitados` está en la tabla `solicitud`

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan Realizo el `left join` con la tabla `solicitud` porque necesito utilizar el campo `ano_diassolicitados`

Comment: Pero si solicitud contiene los que han solicitado, es imposible que te muestre los que NO han solicitado nada. Es RIGHT JOIN, pienso

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan Vale entonces, con esta sentencia, como puedo hacer que me muestre todos, incluidos los que no han solicitado

Comment: Prueba RIGHT JOIN y INNER JOIN, uno de ambos o ambos tiene que dar resultado (creo). Googlea las imágenes con la búsqueda "JOIN MySQL" para verlo gráficamente, ya que así es más fácil entenderlo, que explicándolo.

Comment: El problema que tenes es el siguiente. El join es correcto. Pero despues hay un where, y eso elimina el join. Vos le decis traeme todo lo de users y unilo a solicitudes... Pero solo con año 2019.. y ahi se van todos los que en el join dieron null. deberias decir que son con año 2019 o null, y ahi deberias ver todos.

Comment: @gbianchi Habría alguna forma de pasar esa sentencia a PHP? Creo que con PHP ese objetivo podría quedar mejor reflejado. Haciendo los pasos que tu me comentabas de decirle que me mostrara los que tambien son null, no me dá el resultado esperado

Comment: No se que tiene que ver PHP aca o que es lo que queres pasar. Si no te da el resultado que vos esperas, entonces deberias mostrar los datos que tenes, que resultado queres, que resultado recibis y las estructuras de las tablas